# MySql to Hsqldb migration with engine=InnoDb in sql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, flyway

I am creating a spring profile for dynamic environments in gitlab and don't want to create a separate mysql db for each instance, so what I try is to use my existing liquibase migrations with hsqldb in that speciffic profile, which seems to work besides the engine=InnoDb part in the sql.
I already added `sql.syntax_mys=true` to the datasource url, which supported the datatypes, not the engine part tho.

Since I want to avoid writing different sql migrations for the dynamic environments and already have a prod instance changing the migration or adding separate migrations is not really an option for me.

Is there a way to tell hsql to just ignore that part, or define it as some function which does nothing?

An example sql would be:

```
create table if not exists xy(
    field1             varchar(255) not null,
    field2  ....
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports comments, including a special format for conditional execution:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html

> If you add a version number after the `!` character, the syntax within the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is greater than or equal to the specified version number. The KEY_BLOCK_SIZE keyword in the following comment is executed only by servers from MySQL 5.1.10 or higher:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1(a INT, KEY (a)) /*!50110 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024 */;
> ```

HSQLDB also supports comment syntax in SQL statements: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#N124ED

> All these types of comments are ignored by the database.

Based on this, you could put the `ENGINE=InnoDB` into a comment so that HSQLDB will ignore it, but MySQL will run it:

```
create table if not exists xy(
    field1             varchar(255) not null,
    field2  ....
) /*!10000 engine=InnoDB; */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will do this in the future, for now I have to skip flyway database creation and stick to what hibernate auto ddl produces for the dynamic environments, snice I cannot change my existing migrations. (Which would break my prod env)

Answer (score 1):

An automatic stripping feature will be added to HSQLDB in the next version.

In the meantime, you could modify the source code of JDBCStatement to check and strip the string when it is submitted.

Update: A snapshot jar with this feature is now available at http://hsqldb.org/download